# CMake. Include another cmake project using its CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

I have a `third_party` directory with another cmake project in it. How can I add includes and sources of that project into my project? I tried to use `include third_party/project/CMakeLists.txt` but it gives me error something like 'can't find directory "X"'. I thing its because when I use `include()` it doesn't change working directory to `third_party/project` but uses my root project's one. Directory "X" exists in that project I want to add. What can I do in that case?

Comment: Other `CMakeLists.txt` files are usually "included" with [add_subdirectory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_subdirectory.html) command. You need to pass *relative* directory, which contains given `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev other `CMakeLists.txt` defines `set()` with all headers and sources that is empty if I use `message(ERROR ${SOMEVAR})` in my root cmakelists. Using `add_subdirectory` I have to `#include` them using path `third_party/project/include/some_file.h`. Is this right behaviour?

Comment: Normally, the command `set()` defines the variable only in the current directory and above. The variable's value isn't propagated into the upper directories. Why do you need sources of the another project? What prevents you to build that project as is, and then use its libraries, headers, etc. in your project?